# Finding string between two strings using regular expressions

Tags: xml, regex

I have an XML file where I need to find a string, but only if it exists between two other stings.

For example:

```
<data name="gDefaultTheme" xml:space="preserve">
<value>Temaet "Standard" kates.</value>
</data>
<data name="gCannot" xml:space="preserve">
<value>Temaet "{0}" er satt som staettes.</value>
</data>
```

In the xml above I need to find the double quotes in the `<value>` tags, but not to find any double quotes in the XML itself.

The closest I have come so far is `(?<=<value>)(.*?)(?=</value>)`, but this just selects all the text between the value tags.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use an XML parser?

Answer (score 0):

It's XML. Use an XML parser for whatever platform you're using. You can't reliably do this with regexp for all but the simplest, most constrained scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I can not use a parser to process the data. Basically the double quotes should not be there and I want to use Notepad++ to do a find and replace on multiple files. This is why I need the regex to find all the double quotes between the value tags.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following Regex...

```
(?<=<value>.*?\").*(?=\".*</value>)
```

Comment: Have you tested that?  The OP hasn't stated which regex flavor he's using, and very few flavors support variable-length lookbehinds.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However this has not worked. I got the error "invalid regular expression in Notepad++". I am a regex n00b so I dont know which flavour to refer to myself. Ultimately I want to use Notepad++ to find all the double quotes in the value tags so I can replace them. I also tested this regex in http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ and it didnt work here.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use lookarounds if you don't have to; they're just making your problem more difficult.  It's usually much easier to use capturing groups, like so:

```
<value>[^<"]*"([^"]+)"
```

The `[^<"]*` after the tag ensures that the string you match is actually in that element's content, as opposed to being in an attribute value or in another element entirely.  The `("[^"]+")` part saves the quoted string in capturing group #1.  If you want the string without the quotes, you can change it to `"([^"]+)"`.

There shouldn't be any need to match the rest of the content and the closing tag.  I am of course assuming there will at most one quoted string in any `<value>`'s content.

Comment: Thank you Alan for your comment. However this did not work for me. The first regex you mention selects `<value>Temaet "Standard"`. I may not have explained myself clearly, but I only want to select the double qoutes, not the strings between the double quotes. I could rephrase to I want to select stringToFind in the following `startString some text **stringToFind** some text endString`

Comment: Note in this instance the stringToFind is a single character. That character being the ". If it appears multiple times then I want to find all of them.